# Xpath expression in mule fo each scope

Tags: xpath, foreach, mule

I have below XML

```
    <response>
    <data-table filter="XXX" count="26">
    <columns>
    <column>sampm</column>
    <column>sampn</column>    
    </columns>
    <rows>
    <row attr="535545">
    <field>sampx</field>
    <field>sampy</field>
   </row>
    <row attr="535548">
    <field>samp1</field>
    <field>samp2</field>
    </row>
    </rows>
    </data-table>
    </response>
```

From this response I have to loop over rows i.e; `/response/data-table/rows/row`
So here is my mule code snippet with for each

```
 <http:request config-ref="HTTP_REQUEST" path="api/query" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" followRedirects="true">                
            </http:request>
            <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
            <foreach collection="#[xpath3('//response/data-table/rows')]" doc:name="For Each">
                <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </foreach>
```

But I am getting a warning "`The expression does not evaluate to a type that can be split: java.lang.String"`

Is there any work around this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the `xpath3` return type to be a `NODESET`:

```
<foreach
    collection="#[xpath3('//query-response/data-table/rows', payload, 'NODESET')]"
```

This should be iterable.

Comment: I tried your suggestion.So now there is no warning"The expression does not evaluate to a type that can be split: java.lang.String" But the logger inside foreach gives the payload as [rows: null] whereas I want logger should print <row primary-key="535547"> <field>KAT002</field> <field>Inbound</field> <field>MATT1104133</field> <field>Discharge</field> <field>14-Apr-2016 1249</field> </row>

Comment: That's because you're iterating DOM nodes, not Strings. Try to use a `object-to-xml-transformer` to transform each iterated value into an XML string. If not working, use step-debug to figure out exactly the type of each row and render it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

`Rows` would return you an object, try changing your expression to `xpath3('//query-response/data-table/rows/row')`